# archive-like format using XML

Tags: xml, xslt, format, archive, tar

I'm generating some code using `XSLT` but the generated sources should be localized in a set of *distinct* files. Is there a tool/format (based on XML ?) that could be used to store the files in a jar/ar/tar-like format . I'm thinking of something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<archive>
<file path="test/Test01.java" content-type="plain-text" checksum="something">
package test;
public class Test01
 {
 }
</file>
<file path="test/data.properties" content-type="plain-text" checksum="something">
prop1=value1
</file>
</archive>
```

**Updated**
So I want to generate this kind of XML-archive:
using

```
xsltproc xml2java.xslt my-structure-defined-as-xml.xml > myarchive.xml
```

or

```
my-xar-tool cvf myarchive.xml test/data.properties test/Test01.java
#adding  test/data.properties
#adding  test/Test01.java
```

and to extract the content of this archive:

```
my-xar-tool xvf myarchive.xml
#extracting  test/data.properties
#extracting  test/Test01.java
```

Is there already an existing XML Schema describing such archive ?

Comment: I feel I am not the one who cannot understand your question. As I know all format you specified are binnary compression or packaging file formats. Or you just about structure of the XML file?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Forgot about the binary aspect of the archive. I just want to know is a standard format for grouping some distincts files in a unique XML file. Then I would imagine a tool (let's call it 'xar' that would create the files:

     xsltproc xml2java.xsl model.xml > myarchive.xml
or 
     xar xvf myarchive.xml

or create an archive

     xar cvf myarchive.xml test/data.properties test/Test01.java

Comment: So basically all you want to do is join a set of text files into a single XML file, along with some meta data?

Comment: I want to know  if there is already a XML schema describing this kind of archive, and if there is  already tool packing/unpacking the files. Else I will design this format and create this tool.

Comment: Does WDDX cover what you need?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I've implemented **Xar** the tool I needed. See http://code.google.com/p/lindenb/wiki/Xar